# What's more efficient to keep the fstream open or to open it every time it needs to be used?

Tags: c++, performance, logging, coding-style, fstream

My question is that, what's better to open an stream and close it when the program is over or to open it every time I want to use it.
I'll put an example.
This is a simple Looger class:

```
class Logger
{
    Logger()
    {
         f.open("log.txt", std::ofstream::trunc);
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
         f.close();
    }
 public:
    static void log(const std::string& message)
   {
       static Logger l;
       l.f<< message<<'\n';
   }
 private:
 std::osftream f;
};
```

Would it better to be like that?:

```
class Logger
{
    Logger()
    {
        f.open("log.txt", std::ofstream::trunc);
        f.close()
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
    }
 public:
    static void log(const std::string& message)
    {
       static Logger l;
       l.f.open("log.txt", std::ofstream::app);
       l.f<< message<<'\n';
       l.f.close();
    }
 private:
 std::osftream f;
};
```

Comment: Opening and closing files is an operation that takes time (not all that much, but measurable). Then, the version that continuously opens and closes the file is *less efficient*.

Comment: I would suspect that keeping it open would be the fastest, but the only way to know for sure would be to benchmark it. Also, you may want to flush if you want to use this log for debugging crashes.

Comment: Efficiency is something to strive for, but sometimes you want the slower approach. The beauty of the second is the file is closed between writing logs and there are many reasons you might want this behaviour. For example, you could delete the file or move it to another location so you have a nice, clean log for whatever experiment you plan next.

Comment: In fact, if you are using something like [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), you probably should *not* keep the file open (although it does have options to compensate if a program does that anyways)

Comment: There is no definite answer to this question.   It depends on what your measure of efficiency is and what resources are available (memory for buffers, quotas that limit how many files your program can have open at a time, etc etc) versus what your program uses (how many file streams are open simultaneously) and performance of devices and caching by the operating system (e.g. writing to a RAM drive takes less time but consumes more system memory than writing to a hard drive).

Comment: In c++ there is the famous equation `E != stdstream` where E stand for efficiency. If you want efficiency use os specific syscalls!

Answer (score 4):

In general you would want to keep a file open, because your program might be very unhappy if the file was somehow replaced by the user. For example, see what happens if you save an edit to a long-running .bat or bash script. Also, there are speed issues with opening and closing files.

On the other hand for detailed logging during development, the benefit that the log file state is closed after each message, despite any level of crash that might even prevent the OS from saving any buffered content even after it is flush()ed, and that some other tool can rotate in new log files, may mean that the benefits are worth it, but only for logging.

On the other hand writing your own log file cycling is not particularly difficult (close and reopen with the next name very few MB), and the speed advantage of keeping the file open may make the logging more attractive.

Comment: Flushing the output after each logging message would work well.  Usually, the OS will update the file after a flush.

Comment: Usually, but not necessarily, and it might always be that bit of the output you really wanted! But I must admit the isue is much rarer than it used to be.

Comment: What OS loses data after a flush? The only case that I can think of is OS crash. If the app crashes, the OS (POSIX systems) keeps the buffers until it writes them to disk, despite the crash. As for Windows, I don't know, but I hope it is the same.